# Automatic notification at a specific time

Tags: java, android, time, notifications, calendar

What I am trying to make is to have a notification which is going to go off on the exact same time everyday. I'd like to keep as simple as possible as I'm still a semi beginner.

Here's my MainActivity:

```
private static final int notificationId = 4242;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initChannels(this);

    // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("This is the title")
            .setContentText("This is the body of the notification.")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

public void initChannels(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return;
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
            "Channel name",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

What my code currently does is absolutely nothing. I believe the code should send a notification when I start the app, but that's not happening either. I think the first step would be to at least make the notification work. And then set it to work at a specific time (let's say 9am).

**EDIT:** The code has been fixed to make it work at least. Now when I enter the app, I get a notification, as was originally planned. The second part of my question is how to make it go off on exact same time every day?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

However, to reduce consumption of battery, the Alarm Manager doesn't give an alarm at the exact time, and this policy is different per Android Platform.

You can find more information about Alarm Manager [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

> Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.

Comment: I don't believe you helped me. I said that my notification doesn't work yet and I first need help with that. Do you have any tips?

Comment: I understood.
Could you check when do you call initChannels method? As you know before notify a notification, the channel should be made but I can't find a code about this.

Comment: When creating mBuilder, isn't the second parameter, called "default", the channel? Isn't the channel made there too?

Comment: Second parameter means a channel name what this notification will use. And then the channel has to be made before show notification.

Could you try to call the initChannels method after the setContentView method?

Comment: My notification works thanks to you now, thanks! About having it once a day, could explain Alarm Manager more to me? Could you help me implement it into my code?

Comment: It sounds good @pantank14! I can implement code with Alarm Manager on yours but I recommend you read [this official document](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) and implement yourself because alarm manager has many limitations what you should check.

Comment: I definitely will check out Alarm Manager! I also found some nice tutorials on it. Nevertheless, I would highly be grateful if you could implement the code, since that would give me one more source for learning and future reference. Thanks!

Comment: I have looked up Alarm Manager and I believe I fairly understand it. What I don't understand is this "broadcastreceiver" that I need for Alarm Manager. How am I supposed to put my notification into the alarm manager?